# How get the name of first called child class inside the (super) parent class in php

Tags: php

Suppose we have three classes like these:

```
class A {
    public function name(){
        echo get_called_class();
    }
}


class B extends A {
    public function name(){
        parent::name();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public function name(){
        parent::name();
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->name(); //Result is C
```

If you run this code, the result will be "C". 
However, I need the name of first child class, "B".
Is there any Idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun one, thanks for the interesting question!

The following code will give you the ability to obtain the first child of the root parent from any child class.

```php
class A {
    public function name(){
        return 'Undefined';
    }

    protected function identify_first_child() {
        $root = self::class;
        $node = static::class;
        $parent = get_parent_class($node);

        while ($parent !== $root) {
            $node = $parent;
            $parent = get_parent_class($parent);
        }

        return $node;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function name(){
        return $this->identify_first_child();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public function name(){
        return $this->identify_first_child();
    }
}

class D extends A {
    public function name(){
        return $this->identify_first_child();
    }
}

class E extends D {
    public function name(){
        return $this->identify_first_child();
    }
}

class F extends A {
    public function name(){
        return $this->identify_first_child();
    }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->name() . '<br>';

$b = new B();
echo $b->name() . '<br>';

$c = new C();
echo $c->name() . '<br>';

$d = new D();
echo $d->name() . '<br>';

$e = new E();
echo $e->name() . '<br>';

$f = new F();
echo $f->name() . '<br>';
```

This will output the following:

```
Undefined
B
B
D
D
F
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ArchCodeMonkey! It was interesting solution and works.